# count elements in array not array size

Tags: c++, arrays

I realized that `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` returns the size of the array and not the actual number of elements in the array.

```
   int main(void) 
{

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    int arr[5] = {a, b};

    int arrcount = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    printf("Array Size: %d\n", arrcount);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

`arrcount` here equals to 5. Is there a way to get the number of elements equal `2` in this scenario without changing the array size?

Comment: Your array contains `1 2 0 0 0`. The 0s still exist.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the number of elements". There are five elements in that array. Do you mean the number of non-zero elements? Maybe you really want `std::vector`.

Comment: `int arr[5] = {a, b};` just remove the `5` here. It is not required when you're assigning to an array literal.

Comment: The size of the array and the number of elements are the same. Arrays are fixed size containers.

Comment: Perhaps the container you're looking for is Boost's [`static_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html)?

Comment: Once you get the rest sorted out, you may find the all-new [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) function handy.

Comment: @chris what if the array wasn't and int type but an object type and `a` and `b` were of that object type. Would they sill be 0s?

Comment: @xcmer, The missing ones are [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), which likely amounts to a call to the default constructor in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I  realized that `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` returns the size of the array and not the actual number of elements in the array.

When you say ***the actual number of elements in the array***, I think you mean the number of elements that have been explicitly initialized to something other than zero.

The only way to to do that would be to iterate through the elements of the array and count the number of elements that pass a certain filter.

```
int count = 0;
for ( int item : arr )
{
  if ( item != 0 ) // This is a filter
    ++count;
}
```

The standard library provides a function for that, [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

```
int count = std::count_if(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr),
                          [](int item) -> bool { return item != 0; });
```